# Mongo primary shell not showing data under replicaset

Tags: mongodb

I have deployed a mongodb replicaSet with 3 servers ( One primary , Secondary and an arbitery )

The servers mongoA are located on one Linux machine and
mongoB(Secondary) and mongoB (arbitery) located in another Linux Machiene

If i start Primary script from mongoB Linux box and start Secondary and arbitery on mongoA  , i couldn't see any of my data ( Collections ) under my db in mongoB linux machine  even though the mongo shell  shows primary , the vice versa is working fine .

The logs aren't showing any error .

Please let me  know if this is expected behaviour in mongob machine  ??

These are the statistics of my server collected from  mongob

```
at:PRIMARY> rs.conf()
{
    "_id" : "nat",
    "version" : 18,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "mongoA:27017"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "mongoB:27018"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "mongoB:27019",
            "arbiterOnly" : true
        }
    ]
}

nat:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "nat",
    "date" : ISODate("2013-11-05T09:57:30Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "mongoA:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 216,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1383315218, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-11-01T14:13:38Z"),
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "mongoB:27018",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 150,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1383315218, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-11-01T14:13:38Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-11-05T09:57:28Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2013-11-05T09:57:28Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0,
            "syncingTo" : "mongoA:27017"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "mongoB:27019",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 7,
            "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
            "uptime" : 134,
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-11-05T09:57:28Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2013-11-05T09:57:29Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `rs.status()` mongoA:27017 is *primary* and mongoB:27018 is *secondary*. The status of the secondary is "syncingTo" : "mongoA:27017" - which means that the secondary is still syncing to the primary (mongoA).

You need to wait for the servers to sync and then try again.

Comment: Thank you very much Christian , it was in syncingTo since 3 and half hours , is there any way i can see the progress ??

Comment: I don't think you can follow the progress. There's a JIRA ticket opened but it's still unresolved. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9115

Answer (score 0):

Your rs.status() output is showing that the primary and secondary should contain the same data. because the value of **optime** is identical on both nodes ("**optime**" refers to the oplog entry that each node contains)

```
        "optime" : Timestamp(1383315218, 1),
```

This means you should be seeing the data on mongoA and mongoB.

try running the following command to see what databases you have:

```
show dbs
```

if you see you application database then you should be good.

(otherwise, please explain how you came to the conclusion that the data isn't there)